# Конвертация и отображение шрифтов

Tags: вёрстка, css

Подключил шрифты:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'helveticaneuecyrlight';
    src: url('helveticaneuecyr-light.eot');
    src: url('helveticaneuecyr-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('helveticaneuecyr-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('helveticaneuecyr-light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('helveticaneuecyr-light.svg#helveticaneuecyrlight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Для конвертации шрифтов использовал http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
Но шрифты отображаются криво в chrome, safari.

[image]

Можно ли это дело поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот же шрифт, сконвертированный с другими настройками стал отображаться правильно. Настройки:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

найдите аналог нужного шрифта и попробуйте его поставить